# LDAP/S signing with jbossweb / tomcat55

Tags: tomcat, jboss

To start applying some hardening group policies in my domain controller, I've set the "LDAP server signing requirements" DC policy to "Require signing".

After this, I have a problem to login to a jbossweb / tomcat55 webapp with my domain account.
I didn't face the same problem with other apps (IIS for example).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to tell us how you are performing the bind. That's where you specify signing and sealing.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have access to this info as the app vendor has terminated its presence years ago, and I'm a newly hired IT support engineer. I do have a access to the server though (Win Server 2012 R2).

Comment: A marooned application on an off topic end of life operating system.